# As a Sex offender Can a person for take my Photo off my Facebook page, post it, giving my full name and address be charged or sued?

Tags: defamation, libel, harassment

I pleaded guilty to a charge of child molestation over 15 years ago, served time and probation. I now have three girls 7,5,2 who I father on my own. My neighbor's daughter play's with my girls, who's mother later found out that I have a charge of child molestation. She went to facebook found my profile, took two photo's of me and posted a public post with my full name, address what my house looks like and talked about my three girls all in this post. This is in the state of Georgia. She stated that I do all of the little girls hair in the neigborhood, and I don't.I have already had one person come to my house because of this post. And as Ive stated I have three girls. Whether someone feels as if I did do the crime or not, this is wrong to bring this around my girls. Is there anything I can do? She never came to me seeking out answers as to what did or didn't happen. She feels as if I betrayed her trust by not telling her. In her last statement she told me "since I don't want to let people know, that she will let everyone know.

Comment: There is only one thing you should do, and that's get a lawyer, not take advice from internet strangers on what could easily be the destruction of your life.

Comment: Without knowing your jurisdiction, this is unanswerable (besides @Nij's "lawyer up").

Comment: I agree, lawyer up. We don't give legal advice here.

Answer (score 3):

> this is wrong to bring this around my girls. Is there anything I can do?

If my understanding is correct, your primary concern is the harassment your daughters might endure as a result of the publication(s). In that case, you might want to send the publisher a *cease and desist* letter where you ask the removal of sensitive information about your daughters. If the publisher does not comply within reasonable time, consider pursuing injunctive relief in court. Labels, remedies, and procedural details depend on the laws of the [unspecified] jurisdiction where this is happening.

Other than that, the number of gaps and confusing details in your description render your question unanswerable. For instance, your description indicates that the "*neighbor's daughter*" is the person who learned about the charges, retrieved your full name and address, and so forth. A kid playing with children of age 7, 5, 2 is unlikely to engage in that elaborate conduct, unless the kid is at least few years older.

It is also unclear what happened when the other person came to your house "*because of this post*". There are no details whatsoever, whence one is unable to grasp the extent to which that person's opinion of you and/or your daughters was influenced by the publication. The person's intent might have been to hear your side of the story, to make a proposal, to reproach, etc. There is no way to discern the substance or relevance of that event.

Comment: Who downvoted this answer and why?